# Explicit Element Wait vs Explicit Page Load wait

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

```
IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.00));

 wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
Element.click();
```

vs

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xPath)));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath)).click();
```

Ok which approach is better? I know that sometimes an element will not be present on the page and I want to account for it soonest possible(To not waste time waiting for the explicit wait to throw an exception).

I am trying to parse the error soonest possible, my only fear is that even after the document.readyState is complete the element will still not be there, or that the document sometimes will never reach that state because the javascript will keep executing, and editing the DOM.